# Raspberry Pi Mobile Phone Control

Tags: hardware, remote

Okay, so I had this idea where I could put a Raspberry Pi into my letterbox with a proximity sensor connected to its GPIO (all battery powered), and it could text me when I get post.

I have done the research into the functional element (Pi, prox sensor, python to make it all work) but I'm having trouble with the communication element. I was hoping to connect the Pi to the internet, and then it could just use the Twilio library - but our postbox is outside of line of sight, and outside of WiFi range.

Next idea was a mobile broadband dongle, but that would haemorrhage battery power.

My latest idea is to put a crappy (one month standby) phone in the box with it, and try to interface the two so the Pi can actually text me. What I have not found so far is anything that might let me control the phone (or indeed, any compatible phone) - does this kind of thing exist? Or are there any pre-existing projects with similar parameters that anyone knows of?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

gammu is the stand alone application with python library for mobile phone control. Here is a good tutorial which I used: http://www.mattiasnorell.com/blog/send-sms-from-a-raspberry-pi/.
But I have another approach to your task: Buy a cheap wireless door bell, attach motion sensor instead the button (you'll probably need a relay) and put this setup into mailbox. The other end in the house can ring or - with additional modification - trigger Raspberry Pi GPIO...

Answer (score -1):

plug a wifi adapter (with hostapd support), which makes your rpi a host, and your mobile would connect to rpi. a small lan with only a host and client....

Comment: You mean plug the wifi into the pi, and use a mobile with wifi to connect to the pi, and then the mobile can either text, or connect to the internet via 3G or GPRS/EDGE.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use radio to do this. Take a look at slice of pi and ciseco PLC offerings. I use these all the time

Comment: This answer needs more elaboration. As it is, it's not very useful.

Comment: Other than pointing to a manufacturer and the exact part he needs

Comment: It could do with more information so that George knows what he may find and how it will help him should he search for the keywords you provide.

Answer (score -1):

see www.marsiot.com , use android phone installed this app, you can remote control pi's GPIO, very simple

Comment: We're trying a new policy with regard to informationless link-only answers here. If this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.